# LINQ: I have 3 tables and I want to make 2 join tables

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have three tables, Question, SubjectType and CoreValue.

Question table has many to many association to SubjectType table and CoreValue table.

I want to make 2 join tables: one between Question and SubjectType and one between Question and CoreValue.

How do I make sure that the Association tables with CoreValue FK and Question FK gets filled without inserting any values in Corevalue? CoreValue Table already have the values that is needed. I just need to be able to have FK on Question and Corevalue in same association table without inserting any data same goes to Question and SubjectType.

Thanks for advice!

Best Regards!

Comment: Hi, multi-personality? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375453/insert-data-into-three-different-tables-using-linq-mvc-and-ef#comment11842474_9375453

Comment: Ah. Is this EF or L2S? EF code first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the tables as [pure join tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee373856.aspx) in the database.

EF will generate a model with navigation properties (Question - SubjectTypes, and so on). You probably want to remove the associations SubjectType.Questions and CoreValue.Questions.

See also [this tutorial](http://learnentityframework.com/LearnEntityFramework/tutorials/many-to-many-relationships-in-the-entity-data-model/) (the Class-Student part).

Comment: Why should I remove SubjectypeQuestion and CoreValueQuestion tables? Thanks I will check the tutorial

Comment: Well, semantically it does not seem right that a SubjectType "has" questions. But that's up to you, of course.